# Why does my array return no data when creating a customer with the Stripe API in PHP?

Tags: stripe-payments, php-5.6

I am trying to create both a customer and charge in Stripe.
However, when I try to print_r the array data in my $customer array variable, I get a blank page.

I also tried echoing a string to the charge.php page to make sure the charge page works (echo "page working");, and it does. So I know that's not part of the problem.

The permissions seem to be okay.

These are the permissions for the files in question
-rw-rw-r--   1 sandbox  admin   682 Apr  7 15:55 charge.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 sandbox  admin  1612 Apr  7 17:01 index.php

I have checked my code several times, and no luck.
Can someone help me understand what I might be doing wrong?

Note: The code shown below are all in separate files in the appropriate file types, i.e., all PHP code is in different .php files, and JS in a .js file.
The comment tags are not in the actual code. They are just indicators of where each file starts for the sake of this conversation.

```
     <!-- index.php code below -->
     <html>
     <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h2 class="my-4 text-center">Title of Product Page Here</h2>
            <form action="./charge.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <div class="form-row">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="email" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
                <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                </div>
    
                <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </div>
    
            <button>Submit Payment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <script src="js/charge.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

    <!-- charge.php code below -->
    <!-- Note: Both the Stripe test Key and Stripe PW were masked per Stripe recommendation. Actual test key and password used in real code --> 

    <?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_################');
    
    // Sanitize 
    $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $first_name = $POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $POST['last_name'];
    $email = $POST['email'];
    $token = $POST['stripeToken'];
    
    // Create customer 
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        "email" => $email,
        "source" => $token
    ));
    
    // Charge customer
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => 5000,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "description" => "Audio Loops Pack 2019",
        "customer" => $customer->id
     ));
    
    print_r($customer);


    <!-- charge.js code below -->

    // Create a Stripe client.
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_################');
    
    // Create an instance of Elements.
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    
    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };
    
    //Style button 
    document.querySelector('#payment-form button').classList ='btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4';
    
    // Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
    
    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element');
    
    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });
    
    // Handle form submission.
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    
      stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the user if there was an error.
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
          // Send the token to your server.
          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
      });
    });
    
    // Submit the form with the token ID.
    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    
      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }
```

I expected the customer and charge arrays to return data, but I get nothing on the screen, not even an empty array.

Comment: What is your `js/charge.js` code? The reason is probably create customer and charge customer is never called. 
You could inspect the network tab to see HTTP traffic and console tab to see if there is any javascript errors

Comment: @wsw I added the charge.js to the code examples above.
I can echo the token in the charge.php processing. It works fine. But if I add the $customer and $charge in the PHP script, I don't see the token, $customer, or $charge data.
So I'm thinking the js/charge.js file is working, but something must be wrong when I create a customer or charge.

Comment: put a die(); after print_r($customer);

Comment: @Slavic I tried the die() method after the print_r(). Same blank page.

Comment: @byiton, can you print out your values before `// Create customer ` and before `// Charge customer` and print out the POST form. I am fairly sure the Customer creation somehow is not called.

Comment: Looks like your PHP and JavaScript code is mangled? there's no closing PHP tag, and opening script tag.

Comment: @wsw I added a print statement before the create Customer and Charge objects. The values from the form all printed to the screen. I believe you are correct; somehow, the Stripe objects are not called.

Comment: @Máté I added comments to the example code to make things more clear. Each chunk of code is in a separate file.

And I have only included an opening tag in the PHP file because there is no other code type in that file, just PHP.